# Does H2 support PLSQL when using Oracle mode?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, h2

I'm trying to write some functional tests for our java application using H2 in-memory database. Since we use Oracle as our production DB, some of the code is written in PL/SQL. So I switched on Oracle compatibility mode and now my url looks like this: `jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=Oracle`.

The **actual** application code that I'm having troubles with looks like this (note, both sequence and table have been created before the call):

```
CallableStatement = con.prepareCall(
    " begin insert into profiles(" + PROFILE_FIELDS + ") " +
    " values (sq_profiles.nextval, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) " + 
    " returning profile_id into ?; end;");
```

It fails with the same error that this **sample** code I wrote to test `begin ... end;` behavior:

```
Connection con = connectionProvider.getConnection()
con.prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE test (id INT NOT NULL)").execute()
con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO test SELECT 1 FROM dual").execute()
con.prepareStatement("BEGIN INSERT INTO test SELECT 2 FROM dual; END;").execute()
```

The error I get:

```
Syntax error in SQL statement "BEGIN INSERT[*] INTO TEST SELECT 2 FROM DUAL; END; "; SQL statement:
BEGIN INSERT INTO test SELECT 2 FROM dual; END; [42000-167]
```

So my question is: are `begin ... end;` blocks supported by H2? If yes, what could be wrong with the code above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, H2 Oracle compatibility mode does not mean support for such a PL/SQL. As told in [H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility), Oracle compatibility mode brings following:

> - For aliased columns, ResultSetMetaData.getColumnName() returns the alias name and getTableName() returns null.
> - When using unique indexes, multiple rows with NULL in all columns are allowed, however it is not allowed to have multiple rows with the
>     same values otherwise.
> - Concatenating NULL with another value results in the other value.

Comment: That is sad. By any chance, do you know any other lightweight DB that could be used in an in-memory mode for tests and would provide support for PL/SQL blocks?

Comment: PostgreSQL does provide something similar. But PL/SQL is really very Oracle specific.

Comment: MySQL also has kind of PL/SQL, and quite advanced one. You could emulate your production one.